# Video calling (grandparents)

Tags: video, skype, webcam, video-streaming

I need an extremely simple solution for video calling. I'm planning to use an old laptop with webcam. My goal is that my grandparents only need to turn on the machine and it would automatically start and call me.

I'm planning to use ubuntu 20.04 lts without gui

What kind of video call app can be automated? If I can use it in a script then I'll be able to figure it out myself, but I don't think you can do this with Skype. Is it possible to automate mousemovement and clicks perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many video calling/streaming apps.  Viber and Zoom come to mind.  One additional solution is to install Ubuntu with the Gui. Then setup ZeroTier so you can get to it from anywhere.  Then NoMachine with SSH tunnel into it and do whatever you want. All the grandparents have to do is turn on.  Once you have that working you can script the rest. Automating mouse clicks can be done but I don't think many of the tools are current.

Comment: Better use Jitsi. No need of account and directly runs in browser and also open source.